# calculate left and right children count in binary tree in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, binary-tree

I have a binary tree implemented in sql server 2008 r2 in the following form

**Table binary info**

Parent ID----LeftChildID----RightChildID

1--------------2--------------3

2--------------4---------------5

3--------------6----------------7

```
      1(Root)    
  2   |    3     
4   5 |  6   7
```

and so on. Now i have to calculate count of total members on the left and right side of a member like 1 has 3 left children and 3 right children. 2 has 1 left child and 1 right child.

i can probably do this in c# but is there a way to do this in sql server using Procs or Functions?

I cannot use heirarchyid because the data is already populated in this table.

**P.S** the count needs to be taken separately i.e total left children and total right children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a recursive procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BinaryTreeCount
    @ParentId int,
    @HowMany int OUTPUT
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @childenCount int
    SET @childenCount = 0
    SET @HowMany = 0

    SET @LeftChildId = null
    SET @RightChildId = null

    SELECT @LeftChildId = LeftChildID
         , @RightChildId = RightChildID
      FROM yourTableName
     WHERE ParendId = @ParentId

    if (@LeftChildId is not null) begin
        @howMany = @howMany + 1
        exec BinaryTreeCount @ParentId = @LeftChildId
                           , @HowMany  = @childenCount OUTPUT
        @howMany = @howMany + @childenCount
    end 

    if (@RightChildId is not null) begin
        @howMany = @howMany + 1
        exec BinaryTreeCount @ParentId = @RightChildId
                           , @HowMany  = @childenCount OUTPUT
        @howMany = @howMany + @childenCount
    end 
END
```

It is just an idea, I haven't tested it.

Comment: thanks a lot...the above proc returns the total cumulative sum of the children and i needed left and right total counts separately. i guess doing that will make a proc complex to understand and more prone to errors. I can always run this proc for the direct left and right child separately to get the correct total counts and +1 them...thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on SQL 2008, I am fairly sure that you can do this with a Recursive CTE (Common Table Expression): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Without a copy of SQL in front of me I'd be hard-pressed to show code I'm afraid.